# MySQL Order by sum of another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I currently have 2 tables in mysql; ***comments*** and ***comment_rating***

***comment_rating*** has the following structure:

```
+------------+
| Field      |
+------------+
| id         |
| comment_id |
| user_id    |
| positive   |
| created_at |
+------------+
```

The field positive is either **1** or **-1** 1 being a positive (up vote) and -1 being negative (down vote)

I have this current query which will get me the most rated on comment:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(comment_rating.id) AS rating_count FROM comments LEFT JOIN comment_rating ON comments.id = comment_rating.comment_id GROUP BY comments.id ORDER BY rating_count DESC
```

I Need to know how (using mysql query) I am able to get comments ordered by best rating;
Meaning ordered by the sum of from the rating per comment.

Example:

- Comment X has *2 upvotes* and *4 downvotes* (grand total of -2)
- Comment Y has no votes (grand total of 0)
- Comment Z has 1 upvote (grand total of 1)

The order these will come out will be:

1. Comment Z
2. Comment Y
3. Comment X

Comment: Use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you **juergen d**

Your query was almost perfect:

here is a slightly modified version which will do the ordering correctly:

```
SELECT comments.id, 
       COUNT(comment_rating.id) AS rating_count,
       COALESCE(SUM(positive),0) as rating
FROM comments 
LEFT JOIN comment_rating ON comments.id = comment_rating.comment_id 
GROUP BY comments.id 
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

This way if the row doesnt exist it will be set to zero rather than null and will be ordered correctly.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT comments.id, 
       COUNT(comment_rating.id) AS rating_count,
       sum(positive) as rating
FROM comments 
LEFT JOIN comment_rating ON comments.id = comment_rating.comment_id 
GROUP BY comments.id 
ORDER BY rating DESC
```